# <Link to >route when using <Switch>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am new to react, I have a few routes that I created. The proper way from what I have read is to use a Switch that groups the routes, When I do this one of the Links with the same  route no longer works.

How it is set up in the Nav bar I have a Link for the logo to go to /find route as you can see I have in the navbar I also have a Navbar link going to Find Customers. This route/link works with switch the Logo link does not.

As soon as I remove Switch All links work again.

```
_---------------------------------_
    //Main JS
      render() {

        return (
            <div>

              <Nav />
{/* <Switch> */}

              <Route exact path='/create' component={Createcust}/>

              <Route exact path='/find' render={(props) => <Findcust theCust = {this.state.allUsers} searchRes = {this.searchRes} />}/>
              <Route exact path='/find' render={(props) => <FoundCust theCustomers = {this.state.searched} loading={this.state.loading} />}/>
              <Route exact path='/customerInfo/:custid' component={CustomerInfo} />
              <Route exact path='/DelUser/:custid' component={DelUser} />


{/* </Switch> */}
            </div>
        )
    }


_----------------------------------_
//Navbar Comp

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
     <nav>
    <div className="nav-wrapper">
      <Link to ="/find" className="brand-logo">Logo </Link>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><NavLink exact to="/create">Create A Customer</NavLink></li>
        <li> <NavLink exact to="/find">Find A Customer</NavLink></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

            </div>
        )
```

Comment: Okay when you register a given route, you expect on the givent path i.e ```"/find"``` to render a given view right?
How do you expect to match the second route which is the same as the first one?

The router match always the 1st one i.e ```< Findcust />```
What is the reason to not split both routes, like ```'/find/customer'``` and ```'/found/customer'``` for example?

Comment: Because when the search is performed the results show on the same page, so it happens as the user types.

Comment: Okay I saw your comment edits...So in short duplicating routes is wrong.
Keep the Switch and you've to take a decision:
1 - To split both routes, if there is too much difference between both views
2 - To handle 1 route with 1 View and inside the view split your logic